# Does mounting an S3 bucket as a drive in an EC2 instance copy-pastes or directly saves files in the bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have built a script that scrapes a few thousands of pdf files. I want to build a t2 instance that runs the script for at least 2 weeks continuously and saves the downloaded files in the S3 bucket. I read this [tutorial](https://cloudkul.com/blog/mounting-s3-bucket-linux-ec2-instance/) but I have a doubt :

If I set the download folder to the mounted drive location, then does **mounting** here imply that data will be stored in the EBS and S3 both or that the files will be saved in the S3 bucket directly.

I need this clarification because while building the instance, I'll keep the storage low (~75 GB) and rent an S3 bucket since the total size of scraped files is going to exceed 300 GB.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, mounted drive doesn't take up your local storage so you could just spin up an instance with only 8GB. For the mounting tools I'd recommend https://github.com/kahing/goofys (very actively developed) instead of s3fs which seems to be slow and heats up CPU usage pretty badly if you have large files. I've been using goofys for years with my micro instance plus 300GB mounted drive without any slowness and issues.

Another even better solution is to use aws cli to transfer files directly to S3 without requiring any mounting technique. You can simply write a python script with boto3 which first downloads the pdf then copies to S3 and then removes that pdf locally (that would take only few seconds even for large files).

Answer (score 1):

https://cloudkul.com/blog/mounting-s3-bucket-linux-ec2-instance/

> A S3 bucket can be mounted in a AWS instance as a file system known as S3fs. S3fs is a FUSE file-system that allows you to mount an Amazon S3 bucket as a local file-system. It behaves like a network attached drive, as it does not store anything on the Amazon EC2, but user can access the data on S3 from EC2 instance.

The key point to take away from this is "network attached drive," meaning it will not use any disk memory on your EC2 instance aside from the dependencies you will need to install.

Comment: Thanks! Also, will S3 be reliable or would you suggest that I go for EFS or EBS?

Comment: It should be fine to use S3 if that's where you want the results of your scraper to end up. It should be much cheaper too. Just know that this S3 solution is going to be better for writing than for reading.

Comment: I don't have to read them programmatically. We will download them on our local machines for analysis. Will it be fine then?

Comment: S3 would be better and easier to use anyway in that case. Would you mind accepting the answer if it is agreeable?

Answer (score 0):

If the script you are using is directly copying the file to directory on the s3fs mount, it will not take up any space on the EBS.

If the script copies the pdf locally first anywhere outside the s3fs and then **MOVES** it to s3fs, it is still fine. It will only take up space on s3 bucket.

If the script copies the pdf locally first anywhere outside the s3fs and then **copies** it to s3fs. It will still leave a copy on EBS and take up space there as well. So you need to check - are you copying or moving to S3fs.
if you are copying, replace it with a move or delete at source after a successfull copy.

So even 8 GB space should be enough for the Instance.